# How to Efficently count user's rank by amout of likes?

Tags: php

I have an array, that looks like this,

```
$users = array(
  0 => array(
     'user_id' => 'user_1',
     'likes'   => 50,
  ),

  1  => array(
     'user_id' => 'user_2',
     'likes'   => 72
  ),

  2  => array(
      'user_id' => 'user_3',
      'likes'   => 678
  )
);
```

All I want to do is to implement ratings system according to amount of likes, so that it would look like as:

```
#rank 1 - user_3
#rank 2 - user_2
#rank 3 - user_1
```

I ended up with,

```
$user_counter = new User_Counter();
$user_counter->setData($users);

echo $user_counter->fetchRankByLikes(678);

class User_Counter
{

    protected $array;

    public function setData(array $array)
    {
        $this->array = $this->sort($array);
    }

    protected function sort(array $array)
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($array as $index => $_array) {
            $result[] = $_array['likes'];
        }

        // This will reset indexes
        sort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);

        $result = array_reverse($result);

        $return = array();
        $count  = 0;

        foreach ($result as $index => $rank) {
            $count++;
            $return[$count] = $rank;
        }

        $return = array_unique($return);

        return $return;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->array;
    }

    public function fetchRankByLikes($likes)
    {
        $data = array_flip($this->array);
        return $data[$likes];
    }

    public function fetchLikesByRank($rank)
    {
        return $this->array[$rank];
    }
}
```

My problem is that, this approach lies sometimes - for example it gives incorrect info when there are no likes at all ( === i.e all members have 0 likes) - in that case it gives first rank to them all.

Is there another efficient approach to count user's rating by amount of their likes?
Or what am I doing wrong in my computations? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for efficiency, I would look at the usort() function, native to PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

What usort does is take an array and iteratively walk through it, providing an outside function with 2 items from it's input at a time.  It then waits for the function to return either 1, -1 or 0 and determines the following truths:

-1 means left < right
+1 means left > right
0 means both parameters are equal

Here's a practical example:

```
$users = array(
        0 => array(
                'user_id' => 'user_1',
                'likes'   => 50,
        ),

        1  => array(
                'user_id' => 'user_2',
                'likes'   => 72
        ),

        2  => array(
                'user_id' => 'user_3',
                'likes'   => 678
        )
);

usort($users, "sortLikesAscending");

function sortLikesAscending($a, $b) {
    if ($a['likes'] > $b['likes']) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($a['likes'] < $b['likes']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

If you want to implement this usort() methodology from inside your User_Counter class, then call usort like this:

```
// From somewhere inside User_Counter, assumes User_Counter::mySortingFunction() is defined
usort($this->array, array(&$this, "mySortingFunction"));
```

The function callback is passed as an array with two entries: a &reference to an object containing the function and the function name as a string.